# edit the END TAG ONLY of an element using minidom in python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I am having a few issues with python's minidom, and was wondering if you guys could help me out!

I am trying to convert some xml data from the wrong format to a format that will be read by our system. I have been working on a sort of proof-of-concept and I figured everything out except for this last little issue!

Here's what I have so far.

```
while y < length:

    tag = doc_root.getElementsByTagName("p")[y].toxml()
    xmlData = tag.replace(' region="bottom"','')
    z = z + 1
    xmlData= xmlData.replace(' xml:id="p%d"'%z,'')
    xmlData = xmlData.replace('<p','p')
    xmlData = xmlData.replace('/p>','p')
    print xmlData

    #div.appendChild(doc_root.getElementsByTagName("p")[x])
    print xmlData
    addData = doc.createElement(xmlData)
    div.appendChild(addData)
    y = y+1
```

Now this works great, except when printed into xml I get this

```
<p begin="00:00:02.470" end="00:00:05.388">Organizational Communication and<br/>Deaf Employees<p/>
```

when I need this

```
<p begin="00:00:02.470" end="00:00:05.388">Organizational Communication and<br/>Deaf Employees</p>
```

I think I understand what the issue is, I am appending the child as a string and because of this the element automatically makes a `<>` and `</>`, right? So how do I prevent that last `</>` from happening?

EDIT: mzjn has asked for an example of the xml data.

This is the xml (with sensitive parts removed)

```
<tt xml:lang="MI" ***********>
<head>
    <metadata>
        <ttm:title>*********</ttm:title>
        <ttm:agent type="person" xml:id="author_1">
            <ttm:name type="full">No Author</ttm:name>
        </ttm:agent>
    </metadata>
    <styling>
        <style tts:color="white" tts:fontFamily="Arial" tts:fontSize="24" tts:fontStyle="normal" tts:fontWeight="bold" tts:textAlign="center" xml:id="s1"/>
    </styling>
    <layout>
        <region tts:displayAlign="before" tts:extent="80% 80%" tts:origin="10% 10%" xml:id="top"/>
        <region tts:displayAlign="center" tts:extent="80% 80%" tts:origin="10% 10%" xml:id="center"/>
        <region tts:displayAlign="after" tts:extent="80% 80%" tts:origin="10% 10%" xml:id="bottom"/>
    </layout>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="s1" xml:id="d1" xml:lang="MI">
        <p begin="00:00:02.470" end="00:00:05.388" region="bottom" xml:id="p1">Organizational Communication and<br/>Deaf Employees</p>
this continues with each <p> tag until we get to the </div> </body> and </tt>
```

I need to change it to this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<tt xmlns=****** xml:lang="en">
    <body>
        <div xml:lang="en" style="1">
            <p begin="00:00:02.470" end="00:00:05.388">Organizational Communication and<br/>Deaf Employees</p>
```

Comment: The real issue was I was getting 

'<<p begin="00:00:02.470" end="00:00:05.388">Organizational Communication and<br/>Deaf Employees</p>/>' 

which doesn't work. So I need to work a way around that, and I have to take into account the multiple times after begin=, so I can't just make new tags each time and insert the text

Comment: I figured it out! I ended up using HTMLParser's unescape function and importing the <p>'s as a text node! YAY! :D